# Norm of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Consider the operator $T(f(t)) = \int_0^t f(s)ds$, where $t \in [0,1]$, and $f(t) \in C[0,1]$.

To prove $$\|T^n\| = \frac{1}{n!}$$

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: What is your norm on $C[0,1]$? The sup norm?

Comment: Hint: what is the function $T^n1$, where $1$ is the constant function equal to $1$?

Comment: Yes, so this proves already that $\|T^n\|\geq 1/n!$. Now try to use your computation of $T^n1$ to estimate $T^nf(t)$ from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\|T^n\| = \sup_{\|f\|=1} \|T^nf\| = \sup_{\|f\| =1}\sup_{s_{n+1}\in [0,1]} \left|\int^{s_n=s_{n+1}}_0\cdots\int^{s_2}_0 f(s_1) \,ds_1\cdots ds_n\right|
\\
\leq \sup_{\|f\| =1}\sup_{s_{n+1}\in [0,1]}  \int^{s_n=s_{n+1}}_0\cdots\int^{s_2}_0 \sup_{s_1\in[0,s_2]}|f(s_1)| \,ds_1\cdots ds_n
\\
\underbrace{\leq}_{\text{Why this inequality is true?}} \sup_{s_{n+1}\in [0,1]}  \int^{s_n=s_{n+1}}_0\cdots\int^{s_2}_0 1\,ds_1\cdots ds_n = \sup_{s_{n+1}\in [0,1]} \frac{s_{n+1}^n}{n!}.
$$
Now try to find some $f\in C[0,1]$ such that the bound is achieved.