# How to find the inverse operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A: C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ be a linear operator defined with:
$A(x(t)) = x(t) + \int_0^t x(s)\,ds$.

It is actually easy to see that $A$ injective is, but it a bit of problem to show that it's bijective. Though, the main puzzle is: how to find the inverse operator? I myself tried but didn't far away of the expression

$$
A^{-1} (x(t)) = A^{-1} \int_0^t x(s)\,ds - x(t)
$$

Thanks in forward!

Comment: You can't use $A^{-1}$ before having proved it exists.

Comment: Ok, but $A$ is injective, thus there exists a map $A^{-1}: Im_A \to C([0,1])$. 

However operator $B: C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ defined by $B(x(t)) := \int_0^t x(s)\,ds$ has no eigen values, thus $A$ must be injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f=Ax$ and we assume for the moment that $x$ is differentiable, from 
$$
f(t)=x(t)+\int_0^t x(s)\,dx,
$$
we get 
$$
f'=x'+x.
$$
This is a linear differentiable equation on $x$, with solution 
$$
x(t)=x(0)e^{-t}+e^{-t}\int_0^te^sf'(s)\,ds.
$$
Of course this only works if $f$ is differentiable. But, using parts, 
$$
\int_0^te^s f'(s)\,dx=e^tf(t)-f(0)-\int_0^te^sf(s)\,ds, 
$$
so we may write 
$$\tag1
x(t)=x(0)e^{-t}+f(t)-e^{-t}f(0)-e^{-t}\int_0^te^sf(s)\,ds
$$
Now, $Ax(0)=x(0)$, so $x(0)=f(0)$ above. So $(1)$ says that 
$$\tag2
\boxed{(A^{-1}y)(t)=y(t)-e^{-t}\int_0^te^sy(s)\,ds. }
$$
It is now an easy exercise to check that $(2)$ is actually the inverse of $A$, for all $x\in C[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful! I did not even try supposing that $x(t)$ is differentiable because I thought it could not be expanded to the more general case!  However, do you useful advice on how to show whether $A$ a bijection is?

Comment: You are welcome. It is really easy to show explicitly that $A^{-1}(Ax)=x$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $A$ to be a perturbation of the identity operator:  $A = I - B$, where 
$$
B(x)(t) := -\int\limits_{0}^{t} x(s) \, ds.
$$
If we can prove that the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)
$$
\tag{$*$}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} B^k
$$
converges in the operator norm, we are done: then 
$$
A^{-1} = (I - B)^{-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} B^k.
$$
We have the following equality
$$
\lVert B^k \rVert = \frac{1}{k!}
$$
(for a proof, see, e.g., [Norm of integral operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442476/norm-of-integral-operator)), hence the Neumann series $(*)$ is convergent.